# Can a low-end ARM (Coretex M0+) run enough of a stack to use a USB wifi dongle?

Tags: stack, arm, wifi, driver

I currently use full-blown wifi modules (like Roaving networks RN-174 or the LS research TiWi module (http://www.lsr.com/wireless-products/tiwi-sl)) to interface with lower powered microcontrollers.

However, the low-end ARMs (like the Cortex M0+) are getting very power efficient, and a benefit would be if I could use more commercial wifi dongles (like http://www.trendnet.com/products/proddetail.asp?prod=195_TEW-648UBM) and possibly benefit from additional power savings (the wifi modules I use typically have an ARM processor to run the stack and other parts of the protocol).

Typically, these require a processor running LINUX with a full driver implementation; I was wondering if any driver/stacks existed for the lower-end ARMs to drive a usb wifi dongle?

Thanks!

Comment: what operating system are you intending to use?  Generally, you can run Linux on any ARM device with an MMU.

Comment: "Typically, these require a processor running LINUX with a full driver implementation" - This is so wrong, I can't believe someone would even think of it. Most modems use RTOS, Qcom chips (GOBI modem) use REX OS (which is their own in-house RTOS).

Comment: @user1075375 are there RTOS drivers for USB Wifi Modules?  The ones I have looked into all require linux at a minimum (LS research's modules, for example)

Comment: Do you know what RTOS is ? you shouldn't have asked me that if you did.. If driver code or hardware blueprint is available, you can run anything on any OS.

Comment: @user1075375 I now what a RTOS is; Can you provide me with an example of an RTOS wifi USB dongle driver.  And by USB wifi dongle, I am referring to something like http://www.alibaba.com/product-gs/535165165/150Mbps_Nano_Realtek_usb_wifi_dongle.html

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any M0 or M0+ chips with USB host, but it is available on some M3s, for example NXP's LPC17xx series. An LPC1768 is used in the [mbed module](http://mbed.org/), and there are a few USB host implementations available for it, including a library for a 3G (not WiFi) [Vodafone dongle](http://mbed.org/users/mbed_official/code/VodafoneUSBModem/). There is also a generic USB library for NXP chips - [nxpUSBlib](http://www.lpcware.com/content/project/nxpusblib).

Depending on the dongle, sometimes it might offer not only USB interface, but also plain UART. In a few cases it's possible to access UART serial interface after minor modification of the dongle. If you have such an interface, you don't need USB at all, and UART is available on pretty much any ARM, no matter how low-end.

Please note that getting the USB or UART connection is only half of the job - you still need to discover how to configure and connect your specific dongle. If it uses a standard protocol like USB CDC/ACM and AT commands, that's good, but it's not guaranteed. Sometimes you'll have to reverse engineer proprietary drivers to discover the magic values. Some modules require the firmware to be sent to them on boot, so you'll have to store the firmware image somewhere. Though if it has a Linux driver, there's a pretty good chance it can be made to work.

Comment: Freescale has an M0+ with USB.  I know that source is available for many of these drivers on linux; I was wondering if they can be ported easily to an M0+ without having to run linux on it.

Comment: They can be ported, but probably not "easily".

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky any examples of Wifi dongle having UART interface?